# Spell Check For Aptana Studio 3

Tags: spell-checking, aptana3

Can you please explain how to install a spell checker for Aptana Studio 3?

Comment: [Follow this blog post to install Hunspell.](http://jebaird.com/2012/11/02/useful-plugins-for-aptana-studio-3.html)

Comment: Could you please explain how to download the dictionaries? I'm having trouble understanding where to find the files to download.

Comment: @Randomishlying, you can either get them from the [link on the blog post](http://jebaird.com/media/2012-11-02-useful-plugins-for-apatan-studio-3/en_US.zip) or checkout from the [original SVN directory](https://src.chromium.org/chrome/trunk/deps/third_party/hunspell_dictionaries/)

Answer (score 2):

Install hunspell for eclipse - and stick with eclipse plug ins, because this is what you use with aptana. I also recommend emmet (formerly known as zen coding).